# Passing an NSManagedObject through @State...? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am making a list app which supports multiple lists, where each list can have multiple items. (typical reminders app)

I believe I have written the code correctly for adding a new list, but I am not sure how to pass the list to the 'tasks' view - because when I add a new task to the list, it does not update the view. i.e. Although the item is actually getting added, it is not seen as the view is not refreshed. If I leave the view and come back, the added item is seen.

Do I use a @Binding or @State? How?

Screen Recording: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YoMPkkTKTRSRVaHPSBve_FShAW73D0PL/view

Code for the view which shows all lists:

```
struct TaskListView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@FetchRequest(entity: TaskList().entity, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TaskList.name, ascending: true)])
private var lists: FetchedResults<TaskList>

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(lists, id: \.self) { list in
            NavigationLink(destination: TaskItemsView(list: list)) {
                Text(list.wrappedName)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Add") {
        withAnimation {
            addList()
        }
    })
    .navigationTitle("Lists")
}

private func addList() {
    let newList = TaskList(context: viewContext)
    newList.name = "New List"
    newList.dateCreated = Date()
    let newTask = TaskItem(context: viewContext)
    newTask.name = "New List Task"
    newList.addToItems(newTask)
    try? viewContext.save()
}
```

}

Code for view that shows items in a list:

```
struct TaskItemsView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
var list: TaskList

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(list.itemsArray, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item.wrappedName)
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle(list.wrappedName)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Add") {
        withAnimation {
            addTask()
        }
    })
}

private func addTask() {
    let newTask = TaskItem(context: viewContext)
    newTask.name = "New Task in list \(list.wrappedName)"
    list.addToItems(newTask)
    try? viewContext.save()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSManagedObject` is-a `ObservableObject` so to observe changes in view your need to wrap it with `ObservedObject`, like

```
struct TaskItemsView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
@ObservedObject var list: TaskList                    // << here !!
```